# UITextField selection background color

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Is it possible to **get** `UITextField`'s selection background color without using private APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no public API for that.

You can try it with private API though:

`UITextField` has an instance method named `selectionHighlightColor` and `UIColor` has a class method with the same name. Both return the same color which should be `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.33 blue:.65 alpha:.2]`.

Comment: Opened Radar #14413759 to make it public.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. BTW, wouldn't it be possible to get the color from `NSLayoutManager`, `NSTextStorage`, or similar backing class?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an actual method available, but I just wrote one that does the trick using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. It's unclear whether you want to set the selected background color or just read it? But you can try this out and maybe it will give you some ideas:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectionDetected:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.3;//you could vary this value for whatever you prefer
    [self.yourTextField addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];
}

-(void)selectionDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPress
{    
    if(longPress.state==1)
    {
        self.yourTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];//selected
    }
    else if(longPress.state==3)
    {
        self.yourTextField.backgroundColor= [UIColor orangeColor];//no longer selected..put back to original color
    }
}
```

Until the user lifts their finger (even if they move around the screen), it will remain the "selected" color. Not sure if this is really what you're looking for but maybe it'll help somebody.

Comment: But btw, if you are just wanting to read the selected background color can you elaborate on what for?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [phix23's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17593910/1293167) you can make a `UITextField` subclass and overwrite the `selectionHighlightColor` property. Like:

```
- (UIColor *)selectionHighlightColor{
    return [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

*Tested in iOS 9.3, also in production*

Comment: Thanks but the question was about getting the default color not overriding and setting one.

Answer (score 0):

NO Apple is not providing such apis.